# When Modal Dialog is shown in WPF and a user clicks on the parent window, make the modal dialog flash, blink or shake

Tags: wpf, triggers, modal-dialog

New Thought, Maybe I am looking at this totally incorrectly. So Here is exactly what I am trying to do in case there is another option I am not aware of.

I have a WPF app, the main window shows a smaller dialog window using ShowDialog(), when a user clicks on the parent window that showed the dialog, I need to make the dialog window, flash, shake or blink.

AresAvatar posted a link that looks like it might be able to use, but is there another option I am not aware of?

My original Question.

Mouse click event when Modal window's parent is clicked in WPF app?

I have a wpf app that shows a modal window using ShowDialog().

I would like to fire an event when the user tries to click the parent window that is now disabled.

Is it possible on the parent to receive a click event when it has shown a modal window?
When I attempted this using an interaction trigger, the events never fired on parent window.

Otherwise, what suggestions / options are there.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No WPF events are sent under these conditions.  The only Windows message I can see that gets sent is WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING.  You could check for that message, and check if the window was disabled when it occurred.  Here's a good article on [checking WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING](http://huddledmasses.org/tag/wm_windowposchanging/).

**Edit**: that link seems to be dead.  Here's an example on StackOverflow of [checking window messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365813/hooking-into-windows-message-loop-in-wpf-window-adds-white-border-on-the-inside).

Comment: thanks for the response. Is there any way the modal window can fire an event that there was a mouse click, but not contained in its self?

Comment: It certainly could if you captured the mouse to it.

Comment: @EdBayiates, link is now dead.

Comment: @gregsdennis, added a different link.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I'll post my solution in case any one needs it.

Set the dialog.owner prior to calling ShowDialog().

```
var dialog = new DialogWindow();
dialog.owner = MainWindow;
dialog.ShowDialog();
```

The result is that clicking on the main window, brings the dialog window to the front and makes the dialog window flash.